# Collect unique json data from jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

By using jquery's datatable plugin, I am trying to collect the rows with unique gIDs.I used .unique and able to see the data in console log, how do I replace the table on the page.
**jquery**

```
   testdata = [{
        "gID": 2,
        "name": "An ice sculpture",
        "price": 12.50,
        "cId": 909,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        }
    },
    {
        "gID": 2,
        "name": "An ice sculpture 2-1",
        "price": 12.50,
        "cId": 909,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        }
    }, {
        "gID": 2,
        "name": "An ice sculpture2 -2",
        "price": 12.50,
        "cId": 909,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        }
    }, {
        "gID": 2,
        "name": "An ice sculpture2-3",
        "price": 12.50,
        "cId": 909,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        }
    }, {
        "gID": 2,
        "name": "An ice sculpture",
        "price": 12.50,
        "cId": 909,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        }
    }, {
        "gID": 2,
        "name": "An ice sculpture",
        "price": 12.50,
        "cId": 909,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        }
    }, {
        "gID": 3,
        "name": "An ice sculpture 3",
        "price": 12.50,
        "cId": 309,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        }
    }, {
        "gID": 4,
        "name": "An ice sculpture - 4",
        "price": 12.50,
        "cId": 989,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        }
    }, {
        "gID": 5,
        "name": "An ice sculpture - 5",
        "price": 12.50,
        "cId": 919,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        }
    }
];

var table = $('#test').DataTable({
    "aaData": testdata,
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mDataProp": "gID"
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "name"
    }],
    "bPaginate": true,
        "bFilter": true,
    "bSort":true,
});
console.log(table.column(0).data().unique());
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="test"></table>
```

**Current Result**
Show  entries
Search:

- 2    An ice sculpture
- 2    An ice sculpture 2-1
- 2    An ice sculpture2 -2 2  An
  ice sculpture2-3
- 2    An ice sculpture
- 2    An ice sculpture
- 3    An ice sculpture 3
- 4    An ice sculpture - 4
- 5    An ice sculpture - 5

Showing 1 to 9 of 9 entries
Previous1Next

**Expected Result:**
Show  entries
Search:

- 2    An ice sculpture
- 3    An ice sculpture 3
- 4    An ice sculpture - 4
- 5    An ice sculpture - 5

Showing 1 to 9 of 9 entries
Previous1Next

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not logical

> Expected Result: Show entries Search:
>
> 2 An ice sculpture 3 An ice sculpture 3 4 An ice sculpture - 4 5 An
>   ice sculpture - 5 Showing 1 to 9 of 9 entries Previous1Next

You must remove duplicates and the result will be

**2 An ice sculpture 
3 An ice sculpture 3 
4 An ice sculpture - 4 
5 An ice sculpture - 5 
Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries Previous1Next**

Comment: That is what the .unique function does. I get the result I want in console.log(table.column(0).data().unique());, all I want to do now is to replace/redraw the current table(#test) with this unique data

Comment: table.destroy();
then recreate it using your code

var table = $('#test').DataTable({
    "aaData": testdata,
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mDataProp": "gID"
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "name"
    }],
    "bPaginate": true,
        "bFilter": true,
    "bSort":true,
});

Comment: By destroying and recreating the table with same aaData, how does it solve? Please be mindful when commenting. Comment is for clarification, not to answer.